# Using Stokes in Multiple Variables

Tags: integration

My question is,
Evaluate $\int\int_{S}$ (curl F dot n)dA
where $F(x,y,z)=yi+(x-2x^{3}z)j+xy^{3}k$ and S is the upper half of the sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=a^{2}$

Mostly i can't understand how to lay this out or what it means i can computer the curl of something and obviously a dot product but i don't know what is what in this layout the i and j in the function is really confusing me.

Comment: $i,j,k$ are the $3$ standard basis vectors of the 3d space.
Do you know how to apply Stokes theorem?